# right shifting on non integer types numbers

Tags: c++, bit-shift

i have following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

float f=56.34f;
double d=12.34101;
cout<<(f>>1.0)<<endl;
cout<<(d>>1.0)<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

but it doesn't work and there is this error:

> In function 'int main()':
>   Line 7: error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'double' to binary 'operator>>'
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Is here allowed right shifting in C/C++ compiler? I am using visual studio 2010.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What results would you expect?

Answer (score 8):

That's because, until C++ gets ported to [quantum computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computer), you can't shift by half a [bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit).

In other words, it makes no sense for the [bitshift operator](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitshift.html) `>>` to support floating-point operands. Yet.

Comment: And this half of bit have a nice name `nit` (Nibble of bIT).

Comment: After that we will be able to go even further and shift by complex number of bits.

Comment: There is no such thing as "half a (qu)bit" in quantum computer.

Comment: @KennyTM, not yet, but it's funnier that way.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot shift non-integral types. It is illegal in C++.

If you are looking to multiply or divide by powers of two, then just do that. Shifting doesn't work like that on floating point numbers due to the way they are represented.

If you actually do want to shift the bit pattern of a float, then you'll need to do some casting, or use a union.

```
union
{
  float f;
  int i;
} u;
u.f = 56.34f;
u.i >>= 1;
cout << u.f << endl;
```

But the value you get out is totally meaningless (you aren't dividing by 2).

Answer (score 1):

No, because the binary representation of floats should be opaque (and to actually divide it by 2 you should decrement the mantissa). Use `*0.5f` instead.

If you really want to shift the binary representation (like in Quake square root), use `union` with `unsigned`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to right shift a double? You can `f / 2.0` instead if that's what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Shift operators are only defined for integer types in C++. What would you expect as result from `56.34 >> 1.0` anyway?